# Magento : Problem in Importing the csv file

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I have a csv file with 2 records. but when i try to upload this file through the magento upload module it's uploading more than 196 records. I crossed check with everything in my file only 2 records are there. What's the problem? It's related to cache or index something??
 For your reference i attached the screenshot of the page also.

[image]

Comment: What do those 197 records look like?

Comment: It's the old products i already deleted through the magento system.

Comment: Did any of us give you a direction to look in figuring this out?

Comment: No. But i found the solution for this, its happened because of index problem. But still i'm not very sure about my solution..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have records stuck in dataflow_batch_import that are reimporting.

It's a common problem to have stuff stuck in dataflow_batch_(import|export) and Nexcess has a nice cleanout tool here. [Dataflow Batch Table cleanout](http://docs.nexcess.net/magento-dataflow#here_is_what_we_recommend_for_speeding_up_dataflow)

You can also monitor various log tables for bloat and also look at dataflow table contents with this script to see if you have stuck items before doing another import. [Log Table Monitor](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewreply/277761/)

Dataflow Import also keeps each import file you've uploaded (var/import will get littered with these unless you manually delete them). Make sure you are choosing the latest file you've uploaded when you go to run the profile. The numbers at the front of the file names in the dropdown list are date/time stamps.